# displaying (time )icons equal to duration value on django template

Tags: django, for-loop

I want to display an icon image(of a clock ) several times to indicate the duration of time for an `Event` in my `django` app.The view only supplies a `datetime.datetime` value .I need to find out how many hours,minutes there are  from current datetime and display the icons mutiple number of times.If the datetime value is in the past nothing is to be displayed.

Suppose,the difference between datetime1 and `datetime.datetime.now()` is 6 hours and 30 minutes

I need to display 6 big icons(each indicating 1 hr) and 3 small icons (each indicating 10 minutes)
[image: duration]

What is the correct way of doing this? I think I need to write a filter that returns the difference as a tuple say `hrminutes` (which looks like `(6,30)`) and use that tuple inside a for loop that goes like

```
{% for i in hrminutes.0 %}
  <img src="redcircle.jpg" >
{% endfor %}

{% for i in hrminutes.1 %}
  <img src="yellocircle.jpg" >
{% endfor %}
```

But then for tag expects only a list! It cannot do `for i in 6`

Any idea how to do this..Is my only option calculating the hr,minute values in view and passing it with each `Event` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your filter to return iterables of length n instead of the integer n. For example:

```
hrminutes = (range(6), range(30))
```

That way your for loops in the template will work.